# How to install an authorization plug-in in OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

From the first page of [Apple's Documentation on Authorization Plug-ins](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/AuthorizationPluginRef/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001432-CH204-87010):

> To install an authorization plug-in, you write the plug-in using the API described in this document, [and] install the bundle in `/System/Library/CoreServices/SecurityAgentPlugins`.

However, in El Capitan `/System/` seems to be restricted, even with `sudo`. Is there a workaround for installing authorization plug-ins in El Capitan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new path for Security Agent Plugins, under El Capitan is

> /Library/Security/SecurityAgentPlugins

It appears that the documentation needs updating.

The new path is not so new and also exists in Yosemite (10.10)